# SQL query - Replace/Move some parts of content

Tags: mysql, sql, database

I need to update about 2000 records in MySQL

I have a column 'my_content' from table 'my_table' with the folowing value

```
Title: some title here<br />Author: John Smith<br />Size: 2MB<br />
```

I have created 3 new columns (my_title, my_author and my_size) and now I need to separate the content of 'my_content' like this

'my_title'

```
some title here
```

'my_author'

```
John Smith
```

'my_size'

```
2MB
```

As you can imagine the title, author and size are always different for each row.

What I'm thinking is to query the following, but I'm not great at SQL queries and I'm not sure what the actually query would look like.

This is what I'm trying to do:

```
Within 'my_content' find everything that starts with "title:..." and ends with "...<br />au" and move it to 'my_title'
Within 'my_content' find everything that starts with "thor:..." and ends with "...<br />s" and move it to 'my_author'
Within 'my_content' find everything that starts with "ize:..." and ends with "...<br />" and move it to 'my_size'
```

I just don't know how to write a query to do this.

Once all the content is in the new columns, I can just find and delete the content that's not needed any more, for example 'thor:' , etc.

Answer (score 0):

You can use `INSTR` to find the index of your delimiters and `SUBSTRING` to select out the part you want.  So, for instance, the author would be

```
SUBSTR(my_content,
       INSTR(my_content, "Author: ") + 8,
       INSTR(my_content, "Size: ") - INSTR(my_content, "Author: ") - 8)
```

You'd need a bit more work to trim the `<br/>` and any surrounding whitespace.

Answer (score 0):

Please try the below:

```
SELECT SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycontent,'<br />',1),LOCATE('Title: ',mycontent)+7) as mytitle, 
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycontent,'<br />',2),LOCATE('Author: ',mycontent)+8) as myauthor, 
SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycontent,'<br />',3),LOCATE('Size: ',mycontent)+6) as mysize 
FROM mytable;
```

Comment: Hey Sel, Thank you for your reply. I just realized that there is actually more to it then just moving the content. I should have told you that this is a Wordpress database. Pretty much the table name is wp_postmeta and the columns (mytitle, mysize and myauthor) are all metabox content related to a post. So each post has a custom metabox of mycontent and I need to separate that into mytitle, mysize and myauthor.

Comment: you meant want to update the columns (mytitle, mysize and myauthor) with the extract of strings? If this is the case, you could use `UPDATE mytable set mytitle=SUBSTRING(SUBSTRING_INDEX(mycontent,'<br />',1),LOCATE('Title: ',mycontent)+7) `